# Flask app not rendering data from database (psql)

Tags: python, html, postgresql, jinja2, psql

```css
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}
Search Results
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
fgrgrgtgtg
    <ul>
        {% for book in books %}
            <li>
                    {{ books.title }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
@app.route("/search", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():

        # Query database for book title
        books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title = :title",
                          {"title": request.form.get("title")}).fetchall()
        print (books)
        return render_template("search.html", books=books)
```

I'm working on a project for CS50W and I'm stuck. I'm trying to implement a very bare-bones search function that should find all books in my database by title, and then render them on search.html. I just want to get it to work in the simplest way possible before I start adding more complexities to it.

I added "print(books)" in my python code just to make sure that I was successfully pulling the data from the database, and it appears that that is working properly, as it prints the expected results in my terminal. But nothing appears in my html on search.html.

Comment: use `{{book.title}}` not `{{books.title}}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo; the variable within your loop is `book`, not `books`.

```
   {% for book in books %}
        <li>
            {{ book.title }}   #   here
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow... I should have asked this 4 hours ago. Thank you very much. I thought that the "books" in "{{ books.title }}" was a reference to the name of that table in my database, which is called "books"..... clearly I have a lapse in my understanding. thanks again